# Enable trace-function from org-mode

Tags: org-babel, debugging

I test the following procedure from org-mode

```
#+name: case-2.1.1-factorial.el
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(defun factorial(n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))
(trace-function #'factorial)
(factorial 4)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: case-2.1.1-factorial.el
: 24
```

`trace-function` does not work as expected as from shell

```
1 -> (factorial 4)
| 2 -> (factorial 3)
| | 3 -> (factorial 2)
| | | 4 -> (factorial 1)
| | | 4 <- factorial: 1
| | 3 <- factorial: 2
| 2 <- factorial: 6
1 <- factorial: 24
```

How could make 'trace-function' print the above tracing from org-mode.

Comment: `trace-function` produces its output in a different buffer (`*trace-output*` by default). You can try `(trace-function #'factorial (current-buffer))` but in my experiments that triggered an error in `org-babel-insert-result`. That's probably a bug, which you might want to report to the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: ty, I reported it to mailiing-list @NickD